# How to Implement Interface methods into Another Project using Assembly reference in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I am creating 3 projects:

1. ConsoleAPP
2. InterfacesAPP
3. ConcreteApp

From InterfaceAPP i am declared some methods like,

```
interface IPerson
{
    void Method1();
    void Method2(int i);
}
```

In ConcreteApp I need to implement this inferface methods using ASSEMBLY reference like below

```
//This below code for direct reference. I need to get the methods an assembly reference 
class concrete : IPerson
{ 
    void Method1()
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Concrete");
    }

    void Method2(int i)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Concrete");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just define them as public

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IPerson
{
  void Method1();
  void Method2(int i);
}


public class concrete : IPerson
{ 
   public void Method1()
   { 
     Console.WriteLine("Concrete");
   }

   public void Method2(int i)
   { 
     Console.WriteLine("Concrete");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this code is  using direct reference InterfaceAPP.dll . I need to implement those methods using remote assembly reference.

Comment: What's your mean about remote assembly reference?

Comment: App1 & App2 are independent applicaitons. Earlier if any methods are accessing to one applications to another applicaiton. We are adding direct reference which  ever is going to accesss.      App2-> Right click on Reference -> add the App1.dll . So now i need to load the APP2 assembly in APPDOMAIN and then access to those assembly reference to APP1.

Comment: You can add the .dll file to any .NET application. I can not understand what's the problem with that.